# list problem in Python

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists: first is list that I need to work with and the second is list of -1.
First of all I need to find the remainder of the divison of the number (number is len(lst)) and put it to the position (remainder of the divisor) in the list of -1. **If there is already element, then to the next position in the list (if the next position is not empty, to the next and so on until it finds a position).** How to realize the part that is in bold?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def fun(lst):
    count = [-1] * (len(lst) + 1)
    jar = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        jar.append(lst[i]%(len(lst) + 1))
        if count[jar[i]] == -1:
            count[jar[i]] = jar[i]
        else:
            arv[jar[i] + 1] = jar[i] # problem starts here
    print jar 

lst = [26, 53, 12, 65, 39, 6]
lst = fun(lst)
```

Comment: what is `arv`? (where problem starts?)

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to `lst[i] % len(lst)`? If you are potentially getting floats in the input list, I assume math.ceil would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You introduce arv, but you never assigned it a dict. Since it is a dict, assign arv as:

```
arv = {}
```

I would also use:

```
for i,elem in enumerate(lst):
```

You can now iterate over lst, while also knowing its position.

Comment: You don't declare variables in Python. What you're doing is assigning an empty dict to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The line you indicated with a comment refers to a list that does not exist (`arv`) and I cannot tell what you mean by that.

Comment: but how then to fix the problem?

Comment: No, numbers are immutable. So, there is no problem with `[-1] * len(lst)`.